# How to add public class?

Tags: c++, winforms

Hi im very new to c++(i'm a c# user and want to learn c++)
I have a windows form that have a picture of a dog with label on top of it and 2 buttons
Now I want to create a public class "C_dog" with th ff:

```
public name
public weight
```

and functions:

```
public static sayname()
{
 //when button1 is clicked
  label1.text="Hi my name is "+name;
}

public static sayweight()
{//when button2 is clicked
  label1.text="I weight "+weight+" pounds";
}
```

When I click on add class in prompts me to create a header file and it has precoded things on the .'cpp'
How do I declare new C_dog instance?

Comment: new C_dog() is a way to create new instance of C_dog

Comment: Kindly DO NOT place tags on the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* C_dog.h */

public class C_dog 
{
 public:
     C_dog(std::string name, unsigned int weight);   // example for constructor
     ~C_dog();  // destructor

     // declare all members: weight, name etc.
     std::string m_name;
     unsigned int m_weight;
     void sayname();
     void sayweight();
}

/* C_dog.cpp */

#include "C_dog.h"

C_dog::C_dog(std::string name, unsigned int weight)   
{
    m_name = name;
    m_weight = weigth;
}

C_dog::~C_dog() 
{
}

C_dog::sayname()
{
   //when button1 is clicked
   label1.text="Hi my name is "+m_name;    // label1 has to be visible globally
}

C_dog::sayweight()
{
    //when button2 is clicked
    label1.text="I weight "+m_weight+" pounds"; // label1 has to be visible globally
}

/* get a new instance */

C_dog * charlie = new C_dog("charlie", 40);  // this is your new C_dog

/* if not needed any more, don't forget to send him to heaven: */

delete charlie ;
charlie = nullptr;
```

Comment: Which environment do you use? Visual Studio?

Comment: Can you also teach me about the clicking part?
I mean where to click and what to click?

Comment: Yes im using Visual Studio

Comment: In a VS C++ project you have several folders like: Header, Sources etc. Add `C_dog.h` to the folder with all header files and `C_dog.cpp` to the folder with all sources. Don't forget to include the header files in your sources (`include "C_dog.h"`), if needed.

Comment: It worked! I can use the C_dog class but I can't access sayname() and sayweight() inside the button1 and button2 click event code :(

Comment: You need to have an instance of C_dog visible to both buttons, e.g. "charlie". Then go `charlie->sayname()`

Comment: There are some mistakes in you code: you've forgotten the namespace qualifier for string, you've forgot the * when declaring C_dog and the quotes for the name. Also, better use smart pointers instead of raw pointers. DoN't use NULL, use nullptr or 0. A float or double might be a better fit for weight.